# Clojure - keeping a registry of record types

Tags: clojure, record

I am trying to realize a data dispatching among record constructors. The dispatching is done by a name (which is a string, received with data). And I would like each new record type to automaticaly register for dispatch. For example, in Scala, I would make something like that:

```
object Dispatcher {
  val dispatchMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Creator]()
  def += (crt: Creator) { dispatcherMap += (crt.name, crt) }
}

abstract class Creator[C <: Creation](val name: String) {
  Dispatcher += this

  def apply(consData: ConstructionData): C

}
```

So that each time an object of type `Creator` is created, it is registered in the `Dispatcher` and later can be found by it's name and passed the `ConstructionData` to create a `Creation`.

What would be an equivalent in Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with map and plain old functions approach as shown below:

```
(ns creator)

(def dispatcher (atom {}))

(defn defcreator [name apply-fn]
  (swap! dispatcher assoc name apply-fn)
  apply-fn)

(defcreator :abc-creator (fn [cons-data] (do-something cons-data) ))
```